# django point definition

Tags: python, openlayers, geodjango

my models:

```
class Mod(models.model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    co_x = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 11, decimal_places = 8)
    co_y = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 11, decimal_places = 8)
```

my views:

```
def closedPoint(request):
    location_name = str(request.POST.get("lo", default=""))
    nokta_x = int(float(request.POST.get("x"))
    nokta_y = int(float(request.POST.get("y"))
    poi = Point(nokta_x, nokta_y, srid = 900913)

    sk = Mod()
    poi_s = Point(sk.co_x, co_y, srid = 900913)

    resut_poi = Mod.objects.filter(poi_s__distance_lte = (poi, D(km = 7))).filter(name__in = location_name)
```

here i want to deduct closest point in 7 km but it gives "Invalid parameters given for Point initialization

Comment: why dont anyone not reply anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it's now clear your error message comes from initializing a `Point` class with `None`.

That is your **first** critical problem.

Judging by the error message, my guess is that `poi_s` is initialized with `None, None` as `Mod()` is an unsaved instance with no values and those are the invalid parameters.

```
sk = Mod() # unsaved Mod instance with no defaults
poi_s = Point(sk.co_x, co_y, srid = 900913)
# sk.co_x is None
```

Your second problem that will appear after fixing the above is querying a model with an invalid lookup type (specific to `PointField`, `__distance`) which accepts a tuple. How to solve that, I don't know.

You would have to look at how GeoDjango translates that tuple into a DB lookup.

Comment: actually my problem is i have DecimalField in my model therefore i dont make any query of GeoManager... i dont know how can i fix this problem

Comment: Did you read my answer? Where is the error line? This error is not a decimal error or django error, it sounds very specific to this Point class and initialization Point(X, Y, Z)

Comment: you have found correct place _poi_s = Point(sk.co_x, co_y, srid = 900913)_

Comment: So the first problem is that you're passing in None, None to Point(), unless Point has a special initializer that pulls data based off this srid argument. The error message sounds very specific

Comment: That's one way but doesn't actually have to do with your problem at this line. The underlying problem is that you are initializing a model .. `sk = Mod()`, which has no default values, so `sk.co_x` is `None`.

Comment: is there any suggestion for querying this