# GeoDjango converting coordinate data to GeoManager model

Tags: django, openlayers, geodjango

is there any way converting decimal field to point field so geomaneger model?

i have lots of data which include decimal field of x,y however i dont make any query with django...

my problem is [django-point-defination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327684/django-point-defination)

i am waiting your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have achieved this with some postgis sql code. first of all ı create a new column in my table then i operate with Update postgis code